# Go to Visualforce Page with CSRF protection enabled from a Lightning Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning, csrf

I need to go to a Visualforce page from a Lightning Component. 
The page has CSRF protection enabled.

I'm trying to use navigateToURL action but it causes the "The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator." error.

```
    const navigateEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    navigateEvent.setParams({
        "url" : "/apex/TestVisualforceCSRFPage"
    });
    navigateEvent.fire();
```

How can I direct a user to the Page bypassing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer. It's not very beautiful though.

The only way to go from a lightning component to a visualforce page is to use Apex Controller and

`Aura.redirect(PageReference pageRef)`

method.

Please note, that the Aura.redirect() cannot be covered with unit tests due to "Internal Salesforce.com error" issue. 
To avoid that I have to use !Test.isRunningTest() workaround.

Hope this will be helpful for someone.